# Fixing dates in R

Tags: r

I have data from a weather logger in a .csv file, but for some reason the dates in the first few entries format differently. The first ~200 entries appear like this:

2008-12-20 23:58

and then switch to this:

08/13/20 12:08:24 AM

I cant figure out how to correct the formatting easily while keeping the times in there. The second style is how I want them to appear, as they were recorded in 08-2020 not 2008. Any ideas to fix this in R? I have .csv files for several days and it will take too long to change them by hand

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lubridate`'s `parse_date_time`. It is better to keep date-time in  `POSIXct` format to perform any kind of manipulation that you would require.

```
df <- data.frame(date = c('2008-12-20 23:58', '08/13/20 12:08:24 AM'))
df$corrected_time <- parse_date_time(df$date, c('Ymd HM', 'mdy IMS p'))

df
#                  date      corrected_time
#1     2008-12-20 23:58 2008-12-20 23:58:00
#2 08/13/20 12:08:24 AM 2020-08-13 00:08:24
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `dplyr` and `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date = mdy_hm(substring(date,3)))
```

Here's a sample dataframe, containing your example:

```
        date
1 2008-12-20 23:58
2 2008-12-20 22:58
3 2008-12-20 21:38
4  2008-12-20 8:58
```

Using the method above gives us:

```
                 date
1 2020-08-12 23:58:00
2 2020-08-12 22:58:00
3 2020-08-12 21:38:00
4 2020-08-12 08:58:00
```

Data:

```
structure(list(date = c("2008-12-20 23:58", "2008-12-20 22:58", 
"2008-12-20 21:38", "2008-12-20 8:58")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```